# “invalid time series parameters specified” error in R

Tags: r

I'm trying on randomly making missing values in Canadianweather data from fda package and then filling them with nearby values. If the near value is 1 and 3, I want to have 2 in it.

I want to use `na.interp( )` from forecast package. However, I am getting the error.

```
library(fda)
str(CanadianWeather)
str(CanadianWeather$dailyAv)
missing <- sample(1:(365*35), 100, replace=FALSE)
CanadianWeather$dailyAv[,,1][missing] <- NA
CanadianWeather$dailyAv[, 1:5, 1]
library(forecast)
na.interp(CanadianWeather$dailyAv)
na.interp(CanadianWeather$dailyAv, lambda = NULL, linear =(frequency(x) <= 1| sum(!is.na(x)) <= 2 * frequency(x)))
CanadianWeather$dailyAv[, 1:5, 1]
```

> Error in attr(data, "tsp") <- c(start, end, frequency) : 
>     invalid time series parameters specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `na.approx` from `zoo` package

```
zoo::na.approx(CanadianWeather$dailyAv[, , 1])
```

Comment: What is the difference between "na.interp" and "na.approx"?

Comment: @Alienidea as far as I could understand the documentation `na.interp` is applied on time-series whereas `na.approx` works on dataframes, matrix and time-series as well. They both are interpolation methods though.